# How to display all Jobs that belongs to Company in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to display only jobs that belogs to company in companies/show.blade.php

This is show method in CompanyController:

```php
public function show(Company $company)
{
    $jobs = Job::where('company_id', $company->id)
        ->latest()
        ->get();
            
    return view('pages.companies.show', [
        'jobs' => $jobs
    ]);
}
```

This is foreach in show.blade:

```
@foreach($jobs as $job)
    <div class="col-12 col-md-5">
        <a href="/job/{{ $job->id }}"><h2>{{ $job->job_name }}</h2></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-7">
        <p>{{ $job->description }}</p>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

But it doesnt display anything. Where is mistake?

Comment: If you have defined relation on your model just use $company->jobs. You can read more about relations here  https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: `dd($jobs)` in controller and check if you get any value.

Comment: if the answer helped you, kindly upvote it so it can help other people in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you have define relations as below:

**Company Model**

```php
public function jobs(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Job');
}
```

**Job Model**

```php
public function company(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function show(Company $company)
{
    $jobs = $company->jobs;
    
    return view('pages.companies.show', [
        'jobs' => $jobs
    ]);
}
```

**Blade View**

```
@foreach($jobs as $job)
    <div class="col-12 col-md-5">
        <a href="/job/{{ $job->id }}"><h2>{{ $job->job_name }}</h2></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-7">
        <p>{{ $job->description }}</p>
    </div>
@endforeach
```